# Does pybtex support accent/special characters in .bib file?

Tags: python, latex, bibtex

```
from pybtex.database.input import bibtex
parser = bibtex.Parser()
bibdata = parser.parse_file("sample.bib")
```

The above code snippet works really well in parsing a .bib file but it seems not to support accent characters, like `{\"u}` or `\"{u}`(From LaTeX). Just like to confirm if pybtex support that or not.

For example, according to [LaTeX/Special Characters](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Escaped_codes) and [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57745/13513), `\"{o}` should convert to `ö`, and so does `{\"o}`.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: this feature is now supported by pybtex since version 0.20.

It does not at the moment. But you can read the bib file using a latex codec before you process it with pybtex, e.g. with https://pypi.python.org/pypi/latexcodec/ This codec will convert (a wide range of) LaTeX commands to unicode for you.

However, you'll have to remove brackets in a post-processing stage. Why? In order to handle bibtex code gracefully, `\"{U}` *has* to be converted into `{Ü}` rather than into `Ü` to prevent it from being lower cased in titles. The following example demonstrates this behaviour:

```
import pybtex.database.input.bibtex
import pybtex.plugin
import codecs
import latexcodec

style = pybtex.plugin.find_plugin('pybtex.style.formatting', 'plain')()
backend = pybtex.plugin.find_plugin('pybtex.backends', 'latex')()
parser = pybtex.database.input.bibtex.Parser()
with codecs.open("test.bib", encoding="latex") as stream:
    # this shows what the latexcodec does to the source
    print stream.read()
with codecs.open("test.bib", encoding="latex") as stream:
    data = parser.parse_stream(stream)
for entry in style.format_entries(data.entries.itervalues()):
    print entry.text.render(backend)
```

where test.bib is

```
@Article{test,
  author =       {John Doe},
  title =        {Testing \"UTEST \"{U}TEST},
  journal =      {Journal of Test},
  year =         {2000},
}
```

This will print how the latexcodec converted test.bib into unicode (edited for readability):

```
@Article{test,
   author = {John Doe}, title = {Testing ÜTEST {Ü}TEST},
   journal = {Journal of Test}, year = {2000},
}
```

followed by the pybtex rendered entry (in this case, producing latex code):

```
John Doe.
\newblock Testing ütest {Ü}test.
\newblock \emph{Journal of Test}, 2000.
```

If the codec were to strip the brackets, pybtex would have converted the case wrongly. Further, in (pathological) cases like `journal = {\"u}` clearly the brackets cannot be removed either.

An obvious downside is that if you render to a non-LaTeX backend, then you have to remove the brackets in a post-processing stage. But you may want to do that anyway to process any special LaTeX commands (such as `\url`). It would be nice if pybtex could somehow do that for you, but it doesn't at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for this great information. I did a quick test on `"Heged\"{u}s".decode("latex")` and it returns `Heged{ü}s` instead of `Hegedüs`. Kinda confusing to me now.

Comment: At the moment, the codec does not remove brackets because they matter for bibtex: brackets are used to prevent decapitalization of letters in titles. You can simply remove brackets in a post-processing stage if so desired: ``text.decode('latex').replace('{', '').replace('}', '')``. Does this make sense?

Comment: Interesting! Do you mean `\"u` equals to `\"{u}`?

Comment: @Drake That's not exactly what I meant, but you're correct in that in plain LaTeX, \"u is indeed identical to \"{u}. This all said, it should be fairly easy to add an option to the codec to drop brackets whenever it can. For pybtex I would not recommend this approach, though, because you risk ending up with lower case symbols where upper case symbols were intended. For example, for bibtex (or pybtex), in titles, ``\"U`` is not the same as ``\"{U}`` because the former would be converted to ``\"u`` and the latter would not. Therefore, the codec takes a safe approach and always keeps brackets.

Comment: I've added a full example trying to explain why latexcodec does not remove brackets at the moment; in essence, due to the fact that these brackets are not always redundant in the bibtex format.

Comment: According to [LaTeX/Special Characters](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Escaped_codes) and [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57745/13513), `\"{o}` should convert to `ö`, and so does `{\"o}`. I think I get confused right now.

Answer (score 3):

pylatexenc (https://pypi.org/project/pylatexenc/)

```
from pylatexenc.latex2text import LatexNodes2Text 

latex_text = 'Gl{\\"o}ckner'
text = LatexNodes2Text().latex_to_text(latex_text)

print(text) # Glöckner
```

Comment: What is the relationship to [latexcodec](https://github.com/mcmtroffaes/latexcodec), with which it seems to share contributors? Oh, I see now the latter recommends the former.